# Drupal 7 - menu user access for logged in users?

Tags: drupal

i'm building membership website, and i want to build pages only for users that logged in.
What i'm writing in the access callback to give access only to logged in users?

'access callback' => '?'

Thank you.

Comment: Maye this thread will help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035132/what-is-the-opposite-of-access-callback-user-is-anonymous

Comment: I'm trying your code, and still unregistered users can this the page, any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) function to check if a user is logged in. Like this:

```
$items['custmomenu'] => array(
  'title' => 'yourtitle',
  'page callback' => 'yourcallback function',
  'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following access callback as shown below:

```
$items['mypage'] => array(
  'title' => 'My Page',
  'page callback' => 'mypage_callback',
  'access callback' = > 'user_is_logged_in',
);
```

More info about checking if a user is logged in:

http://oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/2013/01/09/checking-if-user-logged-drupal-right-way